# Invoice total error

Tags: templates, invoice

H All,

do you know why this piece of latex code (invoice latex tex file from Trey Hunner) make some mistake with math?

```
\documentclass{invoice} % Use the custom invoice class (invoice.cls)

\def \tab {\hspace*{3ex}} % Define \tab to create some horizontal white space

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\hfil{\Huge\bf Initech Inc.}\hfil % Company providing the invoice
\bigskip\break % Whitespace
\hrule % Horizontal line

123 Broadway \hfill (000) 111-1111 \\ % Your address and contact information
City, State 12345 \hfill john@smith.com
\\ \\
{\bf Invoice To:} \\
\tab James Smith \\ % Invoice recipient
\tab Generic Corporation \\ % Recipient's company

{\bf Date:} \\
\tab \today \\ % Invoice date

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF EXPENSES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{invoiceTable}

\feetype{Consulting Services} % Fee category description

\hourrow{October 3, 2012}{10000}{.8} % Each separate billing day includes the date, the number of hours and the hourly rate


\end{invoiceTable}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Known problem for years. Sorry.

Comment: For further reference: https://github.com/treyhunner/invoices The template can also be found on *the template site*.

Comment: @Johannes_B What is this *the template site* reference?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina http://www.latextemplates.com/

Comment: what s that rounding issue? register overflow?

Comment: In the version on github `\hourrow` has only two arguments and I don't get your rounding error. But the example in the issues tracker still gives wrong results. The math in the package is faulty. It uses `\real` from the calc package to handle decimals like  0.7 and seems not to know that you can get rounding errors and that multiplying everything with 1000 isn't  enough.  Throw it away. One would have to replace all calculations with something better to get something usable.

Comment: the error is only on the balance due, so i suppose that there is something wrong there, the other multiplication just above is correct.

Answer (score 4):

In the version of the class on github (https://github.com/treyhunner/invoices) `\hourrow` has only two arguments and the rate should be given in another command.   I don't get your rounding error with this version.

But the example in the issues tracker on github still gives wrong results. And a look in the class shows that the math in the package is faulty. It uses `\real` from the `calc` package to handle decimals like 0.7 and seems not to know that you can get rounding errors (0.699) and that multiplying everything with 1000 isn't enough to avoid the side effects of such rounding errors. Throw it away. One would have to replace all calculations with something better to get something usable.

Comment: For cross referencing purposes: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/invoice has the three argument version.