# Changing invoice class tab

Tags: tables, invoice

This is from an older question, But I'm wondering how can I change the below code to have the quantity tab to say "items" instead of "hours?

```
\documentclass{invoice}

\def \tab {\hspace*{3ex}} 

\begin{document}

\hfil{\Huge\bf Initech Inc.}\hfil 
\bigskip\break % Whitespace
\hrule % Horizontal line

123 Broadway \hfill (000) 111-1111 \\ 
City, State 12345 \hfill john@smith.com
\\ \\
{\bf Invoice To:} \\
\tab James Smith \\ % Invoice recipient
\tab Generic Corporation \\ % Recipient's company

{\bf Date:} \\
\tab \today \\ 

\begin{invoiceTable}

\feetype{Consulting Services} 

\hourrow{October 3, 2012}{8}{12} 
\hourrow{October 4, 2012}{6.5}{12}
\hourrow{October 5, 2012}{5.25}{12}
\hourrow{October 10, 2012}{9.75}{20}
\hourrow{October 11, 2012}{5}{12.51}

\feetype{Accounting Services} % Fee category description
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you linked the older question that you referred to in your text. Please also state where you got the `invoice` documentclass from. At least on CTAN, I was only able to find the package `invoice` and the class `invoice-class`.

Comment: Apologies. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263651/invoice-total-error

Comment: You might be interested in using the `\unitrow` command as follows: `\unitrow{October 3, 2012}{8}{12}{items}`

Comment: @leandriis this answered my question. Perfect thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `\unitrow` command as shown in the following MWE:

[image]
    \documentclass{invoice}

```
\def \tab {\hspace*{3ex}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{invoiceTable}

\feetype{Consulting Services} 

\unitrow{October 3, 2012}{8}{12}{items}
\hourrow{October 4, 2012}{6.5}

\end{invoiceTable}
\end{document}
```